# Seeking help for the time analysis of a potential optimization of merge sort

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Wrote this potentially more optimized version of merge sort. The code can be found here: https://github.com/AntonM-248/CodingInterviewPractice/blob/main/IK_Coursework/SortingAlgorithms/mergeAcross.js. I also copied it below. I'm looking for help with time analysis from someone who has more expertise. My thought process was that an array should probably be partially sorted anyway so what if instead of breaking the array down into arrays of size 1 and merging, why not just merge those partially sorted arrays. So for example if you have and array [1, 4, 2, 3], just merge [1, 4] and [2, 3]. It first scans the entire array once to get the positions of the partially sorted sections. Then it puts the start and end positions of those sections into a stack and uses the positions to merge while it scans through the array repeatedly. Then if there is any last remaining bit that hasn't been merged that gets merged outside of the while loop. My time analysis for it was that it would be bounded between O[n] in the best case where the array is already sorted and O[nlogn] in the worst case where the array is reversed.

```
function merge_across(arr) {
  let stack = getSortedSectionsStack(arr);
  let tempStack = [];
  while(stack.length > 3) {
    let end2 = stack.pop();
    let start2 = stack.pop();
    let end = stack.pop();
    let start = stack.pop();
    merge_two_sections(start, end, start2, end2, arr);
    tempStack.push(end2);
    tempStack.push(start);
    if(stack.length == 0) {
      while(tempStack.length > 3) {
        stack.push(tempStack.pop());
        stack.push(tempStack.pop());
        stack.push(tempStack.pop());
        stack.push(tempStack.pop());
      }
    }
  }
  let start = 0;
  let end = find_end_of_sort(start, arr);
  let start2 = end + 1;
  let end2 = find_end_of_sort(start2, arr);
  if(start2 < arr.length) {
    merge_two_sections(start, end, start2, end2, arr);
  }
  return arr;
}

function merge_two_sections(start, end, start2, end2, arr) {
  let merged_section = new Array(end2 - start + 1);
  let merge_index = 0;
  let original_start = start;
  while(start <= end && start2 <= end2) {
    if(arr[start] < arr[start2]) {
      merged_section[merge_index] = arr[start];
      start++;
    }
    else if(arr[start2] <= arr[start]) {
      merged_section[merge_index] = arr[start2];
      start2++;
    }
    merge_index++;
  }
  while(start <= end) {
    merged_section[merge_index] = arr[start];
    start++;
    merge_index++;
  }
  while(start2 <= end2) {
    merged_section[merge_index] = arr[start2];
    start2++;
    merge_index++;
  }
  for(let i = 0; i < merged_section.length; i++) {
    arr[original_start] = merged_section[i];
    original_start++;
  }
}

function find_end_of_sort(start, arr) {
  while(start < arr.length - 1 && arr[start] < arr[start + 1]) {
    start++;
  }
  return start;
}
```

Comment: Worst case you are creating N arrays of 1 element.   Try this with the 'standard' sorting methods and do some timings and memory analysis with like a million random values.

Comment: You run for crescent number of n. You will have a chart that you can do regression, or just by view understand if it's log, exp, linear, quadratic, etc. You can do estimates using multiple cases "best case", "worst case", "random values with fixed seed", etc.

Comment: *"more optimized"*: ...than which version? Please specify what you are comparing with (since mergesort has many, many variants, each trying to bring another optimisation), what tests you have executed to make a fair comparison?